# open dialog using CButtonColumn in yii 1.1

Tags: yii, dialog

i have used CButtonColumn inside TbGridView.On click of button i want a dialog from where i want to send mail to recepient.
My admin.php code:

```
    array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{dialog}',
    'buttons'=>array(
     'dialog' => array(
        'label'=>'Email',
        'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/email_envelope.png',
        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("todoList/OpenMailDialog", array("id"=>$data->to_do_id))',
         'options'=>array(  
                    'ajax'=>array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>"js:$(this).attr('href')", 
                            'update'=>'#dialog_id',
                           ),
                     ),
      ),
  ),
),
<div class="dialog_id" style="display:none;"></div>
```

My controller code is:

```
public function actionOpenMailDialog($id){
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $this->render('createDialog',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

My view code is:

```
<?php
   $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
            'id'=>'mailDialog',
            'options'=>array(
                'title'=>'View Message #'. $model->id,
                'autoOpen'=>true,
                'modal'=>'true',
                'width'=>'auto',
                'height'=>'auto',
            ),
            ));
echo $this->renderPartial('_formDialog', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

My _formDialog:

```
    <div class="form" id="mailDialogForm">

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_from'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_from',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_from'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_to'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_to',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_to'); ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'message'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'message',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'message'); ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="row buttons">
     <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ?
     'Send' :'Send',array('class' => 'btn')); ?>
</div>
```

I am not able to pop up dialog here.What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

i simply chaged my code like this and its working now.My admin.php code is like this:

```
   array(
       'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
       'template'=>'{dialog}',
       'buttons'=>array(
           'dialog' => array(
               'label'=>'Email',
                'imageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/email_envelope.png',
                'visible'=>'$data->user_id===Yii::app()->user->id?false:true',
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("todoList/openMailDialog", array("id"=>$data->to_do_id))',

    ),
),
```

),

My _formDialog.php code:

```
<div  id="mailDialogForm">

 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'mail-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
 )); 

?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="rowcol">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_from'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_from',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'email_from'); ?>
</div>

<div class="rowcol">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_to'); ?>
<?php echo  $form->textField($model,'email_to',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'email_to'); ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div >
 -----------------
</div>
<div class="rowbutton">

 <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ?
 'Send' :'Send',array('class' => 'btn')); ?>
 </div>

 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
 </div>
```